# "Can't get attribute 'ImageList'" using FastAI and PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, fast-ai

Version Numbers:

```
torchvision: 0.3.0
torch: 1.1.0
fastai: 1.0.57
```

For no reason that comes to mind, I always run into this error: `Can't get attribute 'ImageList'` when loading my model. I use `load_learner(".", fname="model.pkl")` to load my model, and it has the relevant files within the folder (`final.pth`,`model.pkl`,`classes.txt`) but it doesn't seem to work at all. I've checked the internet, but I've found nothing with `ImageList`.

The full error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ImageList' on <module 'fastai.vision.data' from '/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/vision/data.py'>`